# Generic programming: Log FFT OR high-precision convolution (python)

Tags: python, fft, numerical-methods, convolution

I have a slightly unusual problem, but I am trying to avoid re-coding FFT.

In general, I want to know this: If I have an algorithm that is implemented for type `float`, but it would work wherever a certain set of operations is defined (e.g. complex numbers, for which also define `+`, `*`, ...), what is the best way to use that algorithm on another type that supports those operations? In practice this is tricky because generally numeric algorithms are written for speed, not generality.

**Specifically:**
I am working with values with a very high dynamic range, and so I would like to store them in log space (mostly to avoid underflow).

What I'd like is the log of the FFT of some series:

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5]
fft_x = [ log( x_val ) for x_val in fft(x) ]
```

Even this will result in significant underflow. What I'd like is to store log values and use `+` in place of `*` and `logaddexp` in place of `+`, etc.

My thought of how to do this was to implement a simple LogFloat class that defines these primitive operations (but operates in log space). Then I could simply run the FFT code by letting it use my logged values.

```
class LogFloat:
    def __init__(self, sign, log_val):
        assert(float(sign) in (-1, 1))
        self.sign = int(sign)
        self.log_val = log_val
    @staticmethod
    def from_float(fval):
        return LogFloat(sign(fval), log(abs(fval)))
    def __imul__(self, lf):
        self.sign *= lf.sign
        self.log_val += lf.log_val
        return self
    def __idiv__(self, lf):
        self.sign *= lf.sign
        self.log_val -= lf.log_val
        return self
    def __iadd__(self, lf):
        if self.sign == lf.sign:
            self.log_val = logaddexp(self.log_val, lf.log_val)
        else:
            # subtract the smaller magnitude from the larger
            if self.log_val > lf.log_val:
                self.log_val = log_sub(self.log_val, lf.log_val)
            else:
                self.log_val = log_sub(lf.log_val, self.log_val)
                self.sign *= -1
        return self
    def __isub__(self, lf):
        self.__iadd__(LogFloat(-1 * lf.sign, lf.log_val))
        return self
    def __pow__(self, lf):
        # note: there may be a way to do this without exponentiating
        # if the exponent is 0, always return 1
#        print self, '**', lf
        if lf.log_val == -float('inf'):
            return LogFloat.from_float(1.0)
        lf_value = lf.sign * math.exp(lf.log_val)
        if self.sign == -1:
            # note: in this case, lf_value must be an integer
            return LogFloat(self.sign**int(lf_value), self.log_val * lf_value)
        return LogFloat(self.sign, self.log_val * lf_value)
    def __mul__(self, lf):
        temp = LogFloat(self.sign, self.log_val)
        temp *= lf
        return temp
    def __div__(self, lf):
        temp = LogFloat(self.sign, self.log_val)
        temp /= lf
        return temp
    def __add__(self, lf):
        temp = LogFloat(self.sign, self.log_val)
        temp += lf
        return temp
    def __sub__(self, lf):
        temp = LogFloat(self.sign, self.log_val)
        temp -= lf
        return temp
    def __str__(self):
        result = str(self.sign * math.exp(self.log_val)) + '('
        if self.sign == -1:
            result += '-'
        result += 'e^' + str(self.log_val) + ')'
        return result
    def __neg__(self):
        return LogFloat(-self.sign, self.log_val)
    def __radd__(self, val):
        # for sum
        if val == 0:
            return self
        return self + val
```

Then, the idea would be to construct a list of `LogFloat`s, and then use it in the FFT:

```
x_log_float = [ LogFloat.from_float(x_val) for x_val in x ]
fft_x_log_float = fft(x_log_float)
```

This can definitely be done if I re-implement FFT (and simply use `LogFloat` wherever I would use `float` before, but I thought I would ask for advice. This is a fairly recurring problem: I have a stock algorithm that I want to operate in log space (and it only uses a handful of operations like '+', '-', '*', '/', etc.*).

This reminds me of writing generic functions with templates, so that the return arguments, parameters, etc. are constructed from the same type. For exmaple, if you can do an FFT of floats, you should be able to easily do one on complex values (by simply using a class that provides the necessary operations for complex values).

As it currently stands, it looks like all FFT implementations are written for bleeding-edge speed, and so won't be very general. So as of now, it looks like I'd have to reimplement FFT for generic types...

The reason I'm doing this is because I want very high-precision convolutions (and the **N^2** runtime is extremely slow). 
Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

*Note, I might need to implement trigonometric functions for `LogFloat`, and that would be fine.

**EDIT:**
This does work because `LogFloat` is a commutative ring (and it doesn't require implementation of trigonometric functions for `LogFloat`). The simplest way to do it was to reimplement FFT, but @J.F.Sebastian also pointed out a way of using the `Python` generic convolution, which avoids coding the FFT (which, again, was quite easy using either a DSP textbook or [the Wikipedia pseudocode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform)).

Comment: i'm not sure what your problem is.  if the fft is written in python, then the above should (modulo the ambitious craziness) work.  if it calls out to a c implementation then it won't work, because the c code is, well, c code that isn't going to do what python does.

so what is the question?

Comment: there is [generic convolution](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~jimc/mathnet_d/sage/reference/sage/rings/polynomial/convolution.html). `LogFloat` might be not the best approach to deal with underflow.

Comment: Lots of FFTs in DSP textbooks and tutorial web sites provide very simple FFT source code examples, usually about 1 or 2 pages of code.  (There are a couple FFTs on my DSP web site that are only 30 to 40 lines of BASIC.)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I'm already using LogFloat, but essentially with a naive convolution and just want to speed it up. Do you know of an implementation (or pseudocode) for the generic convolution algorithm that is not tied into sage?

Comment: @hotpaw2 I know what you mean, and thanks for the pseudocode on your site. I actually reimplemented the Cooley-Tukey algorithm, but just wanted to ask. Usually I turn to stackoverflow when I know of **a way** to do something, but feel like it isn't the **best way**.

Comment: @Oliver: The [source code](http://hg.sagemath.org/sage-main/file/4.8/sage/rings/polynomial/convolution.py#l369) has minimal dependencies.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Thanks for the source code link. Recoding FFT was actually not so bad, but the existing source is nice because it's guaranteed to work.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Could you post a summary of what you said as an answer? Then I can mark this as solved! : )

Comment: If you found an acceptable solution; you may post your own answer: ["it is not merely OK to ask and answer your own question, it is explicitly encouraged."](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I confess I didn't entirely keep up with the math in your question. However it sounds like what you're really wondering is **how to deal with extremely small and large (in absolute value) numbers without hitting underflows and overflows**. Unless I misunderstand you, I think this is similar to the problem I have working with units of money, not losing pennies on billion-dollar transactions due to rounding. If that's the case, **my solution has been Python's built-in decimal-math module.** The documentation is good for both [Python 2](http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html) and [Python 3](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/decimal.html). The short version is that decimal math is an arbitrary-precision floating- and fixed-point type. The Python modules conform to the IBM/IEEE standards for decimal math. In Python 3.3 (which is currently in alpha form, but I've been using it with no problems at all), the module has been rewritten in C for an up to 100x speed up (in my quick tests).

Comment: You're right, I am trying to avoid underflow (I'm convolving densities to compute a probability density function). I'll definitely have to try the arbitrary precision python library-- until now, I've always been a little unsure about the overhead, but it would be very cool if it did the trick. Then I would simply need an FFT coded to use those values (instead of float or numpy's 64bit float).

Comment: `Decimal` objects are slower than machine-level `float`s (which is what Python's `float`s are). If you're speed sensitive and you're stuck on Python 2, I would say find a different solution. If you're on Python 3 or can move to it, upgrade to the latest alpha of Python 3.3 where `Decimal` is written in C (my application is speed sensitive and I've been satisfied with the performance on 3.3). Regarding reworking the FFT -- shouldn't be necessary. `Decimal` objects are drop-in replacements for `float`s. Yay duck typing!

Comment: I know what you mean about duck typing. For some reason I thought most ffts (e.g. the numpy fft, I think) casts the argument to an array of specified type to perform faster computation. Do you know if you can duck type with numpy fft? If so, that saves a lot of trouble!

Answer (score 0):

You could scale your time domain samples by a large number s to avoid underflow, and then, if

> > **F**( f(t) ) = **X**(j*w)

then

> > **F**(s f(s*t)) <-> **X**(w/s)

Now using the convolution theorem you can work out how to scale your final result to remove the effect of the scaling factor.